# ( React Router ) Dynamic nested route generation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question about generating nested routes on the fly.  I'm able to generate routes on the fly if it is not nested.

Let's look at the following example -

```
var routes = [
    {
        name: 'about',
        path: '/about',
        handler: './pages/test/index.jsx',

        // this is a nested routes
        routes: [
            {
                name: 'me',
                path: 'me',
                handler: './pages/test/me'
            },
            {
                name: 'you',
                path: 'you',
                handler: './pages/test/you'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

And I try to do the followings -

```
var ExtraRoutes =  [];

_.each(routes, function(route) {
    ExtraRoutes.push(<Route name={route.name} path={route.path} handler={require(route.handler)} addHandlerKey={true} >);

        _.each(route.routes, function(route) {
            ExtraRoutes.push(<Route name={route.name} path={route.path} handler={require(route.handler)} addHandlerKey={true} />)
        });

        // obviously wrong way to do that :)
        ExtraRoutes.push(</Route>);
});
```

But looks like my syntax is not correct ... So how to inject those nested routes into the parent route dynamically ?

And my end goal is to generate the following

```
<Route name="about" handler={require('./pages/test')}>
    <Route name="me" handler={require('./pages/test/me')}/>
    <Route name="you" handler={require('./pages/test/you')}/>
</Route>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? does it work if you force the handler to be the same component (just troubleshooting).

Comment: Did you solve this? How so?

Comment: I'm very curious to see if this can be done.

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue ?